# Lucene search across different object models

Tags: php, lucene

I am thinking of using Lucene to provide searching functionality for a website.

The website incorporates several different object models (e.g. forum, poll etc), and I would like to be able to allow searching accross the different object models (i.e. search forums and|or polls)

I have two (somewhat related) questions:

1. Do the objects need to provide a consistent (i.e. same interface to Lucene)? - for example, should all objects to be indexes have id, title, content etc properties, or can each object store different data fields?
2. What syntax would be required by a user to search (polls only or polls AND forums [as examples]) for a particular keyword?

I am using the PHP port of Lucene.

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 options.

1. Create a separate index per type of document (forum, poll, etc.). Advantage, simpler queries, simpler documents, more accurate matches (your field normalization isn't impacted by other document data). Disadvantage, having to maintain separate indices, having disparate documents.
2. Create a single index. The Document you store would be the union of all fields from all objects you want to query. You add an additional field which is the type (forum, poll, etc) that you are storing. Then, when querying, you filter by type to get only the results you want. Advantage, single document/index to maintain. Disadvantage, you can get some crosstalk on shared fields that can skew search results.

To clarify on the disadvantage I mention in 2 above. There's inherent weighting in Lucene towards "rarer" terms. If you have a query that uses a rare term and that term shows up in only a couple of documents, those document will bubble towards the top of the search results. If you share a field between 2 different documents in the union, there *can* (not always) be cases where search results are weighted differently than they should be and it's obvious to the end user.

I'd lean towards option 1 for correctness, 2 for ease of maintenance. It's a trade off.

EDIT: If you want to support querying across multiple types in a single query, option 2 is preferable. It's the only way you'll be able to mix results from different document types. Querying 2 indexes and trying to somehow order the results is almost impossible due to scoring algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene uses the concept of "documents", which are entries in a Lucene index. Each document has several "fields", that contain the actual data. You will be able to search whatever you add to Lucene's index, but it's important for those entries to be created with an identifier that allows to match a query result back to an instance of your model.

What this means is that, if you have your data in a relational database, and are using numeric IDs, then the index entry that you create with Lucene will have to contain both the corresponding identifier and a "type" (e.g., the table), which will allow you to know what kind of instance that the id corresponds to.

As to syntax, Lucene provides a very nice google-like query syntax. How you create your Lucene documents/index-entries will shape how your queries are expressed.

Comment: that is a pretty high level overview - which is what I currently have. What I'm looking for is slightly more detail as to HOW I can actually implement the required functionality (preferably with some pseudocode/code snippet), without having to read the entire Lucene manual from cover to cover.